# Set Text not showing from a function inside a fragment

Tags: java, android

I am new in fragments. I am having a fragment which has 3 sides. In my login activity it passes all data by sharedpreference. When I get into my fragment home, it displays the data by the shared preference. In my other part of the fragment is the edit profile. It must retrieve the data I have and put into the set text.

Here is my SideProfileFragment

```
public class SideProfileFragment extends  Fragment{

    private static final String TAG = SideProfileFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    public EditText name, birthDate, address, occupation, gender, number;


    SessionManager sessionManager;
    String getId;
    private static String URL_READ = "http://isalonbyageeks.000webhostapp.com/readDetail.php";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sideprofile, container, false);
        return view;



    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        sessionManager = new SessionManager(getActivity());
        sessionManager.checkLogin();

        name = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.userName);
        birthDate = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.userBirthDate);
        address = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.userAddress);
        occupation = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.userOccupation);
        gender = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.userGender);
        number = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.userNumber);

        HashMap<String, String> user = sessionManager.getUserDetail();
        getId = user.get(sessionManager.ID);

    }
    private void getUserDetail(){
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loadingws...");
        progressDialog.show();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_READ,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Log.i(TAG, response);

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("read");

                            if(success.equals("1")){
                                for(int i = 0; 1 < jsonArray.length();i++){

                                    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String strName = object.getString ("name");
                                    String strNumber = object.getString("phone_number");
                                    String strGender = object.getString("gender");
                                    String strAddress = object.getString("address");
                                    String strOccupation = object.getString("occupation");
                                    String strBirthDate = object.getString("birth_date");

                                    name.setText(strName);
                                    birthDate.setText(strBirthDate);
                                    address.setText(strAddress);
                                    number.setText(strNumber);
                                    gender.setText(strGender);
                                    occupation.setText(strOccupation);


                                }
                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Error Reading Detail" +e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Error Reading Detail" +error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError{
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("id", getId);
                        return super.getParams();
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        getUserDetail();
    }

}
```

I tried setting the text with a sample "text" inside the oncreated view and it worked. but when I put the set text inside the function getUserDetails it did not do anything, my sideprofile just showed blank edit texts.

PS I tried to put a sample text inside the set text of the function, but still nothing went out.

### Edit

This is the XML code of sideprofilefragment that I have. Everything seems so fine!

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/settingImageEdit"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/defaultpic"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editProfilePicture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/settingImageEdit"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:text="Edit Photo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editProfilePicture"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_white"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_user_icon"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:hint="Email/Username"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/userNumber"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_white"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_phone"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:hint="Phone Number"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/userOccupation"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userNumber"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_white"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_occupation"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:hint="Occupation"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/userAddress"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userOccupation"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_white"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_address"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:hint="Address"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/userGender"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userAddress"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_white"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_gender"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:hint="Gender"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userBirthDate"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userGender"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/userGender"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/userGender"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_white"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_calendar"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Tap to set Birthdate"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userAddress"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="101dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:text="Save Edit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What should I really need to change? I tried to put

```
name.setText("sample");
```

inside the onviewcreated, it worked. but when in the function, it didnt.

Comment: please use view.findViewById() instead of getActivity().findViewById()

Comment: provide me response of your api

Comment: @VishalYadav how can I do that sir

Comment: provide me value of `getId`

Comment: it is passed by my login activity sir. by a volley.

Comment: what ever it is man..... i want this id bro

Comment: I have a login.php where it reads the table and pass the data sir.

$response["id"] = $colUserId; it gets this. then in the login activity, it is stated with 

String id = jsonResponse.getString("id");

                                        sessionManager.createSession(id,name,number,gender,address,occupation,birth_date,user_type);

Comment: the ID is directly stored in the sessionmanager in sharedpreference.

Comment: I have downvoted for the hostile rollback. Please be willing to accept good edits to your posts.

Answer (score 1):

Replace all `getActivity().findViewById()` to `view.findViewById()`

```
name = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.userName);
```

replace for all views

also when you receive the result from http request you need to run UI operations on UI thread.
example :

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Log.i(TAG, response);

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("read");

                        if(success.equals("1")){
                            for(int i = 0; 1 < jsonArray.length();i++){

                                JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String strName = object.getString ("name");
                                String strNumber = object.getString("phone_number");
                                String strGender = object.getString("gender");
                                String strAddress = object.getString("address");
                                String strOccupation = object.getString("occupation");
                                String strBirthDate = object.getString("birth_date");

                                name.setText(strName);
                                birthDate.setText(strBirthDate);
                                address.setText(strAddress);
                                number.setText(strNumber);
                                gender.setText(strGender);
                                occupation.setText(strOccupation);


                            }
                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Error Reading Detail" +e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }      
});
```

Comment: OP is using volley so `onResponse()` will execute on UI thread itself.

Comment: @KaranMer ok so he should replace the findViewById only

Comment: sirs it still didnt really come out. i dont understand what did i really miss

Comment: Show the xml code for `R.layout.fragment_sideprofile`

Answer (score 1):

Your views will be contained within the view passed in

```
onViewCreated(View view,  @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

and not your activity, so you need to use it to refer your variables.

```
name = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.userName);
```

change it as above for all views.

Comment: Sir, I really did the change but still nothing came out. What am i really missing? :( I tried to just change the set text to "sampletext"; but still nothing went out

Answer (score 0):

1) replace all the `getActivity().findViewById()` by `view.findViewById()`

2) you need to handle the setting of the UI in another thread

```
    try {
        Handler uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                        name.setText(strName);
                        birthDate.setText(strBirthDate);
                        address.setText(strAddress);
                        number.setText(strNumber);
                        gender.setText(strGender);
                        occupation.setText(strOccupation);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("bugs", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

3) If the problem persists, also give `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to all 
   the TextViews and EditTexts

Comment: how can I implement this sir? inside my try catch method?

Comment: yes, inside your for loop where you are setting the text

Comment: does making my String from the json response final then putting that handler below connect the set text?

Comment: is it throwing any exception ??

Comment: no sir. it is somehow in the try catch but still my fragment has no texts